# Removing commented rows in place in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that may have commented characters at the bottom of it. Due to some other reasons, I cannot pass the comment character to initialize the dataframe itself. Here is an example of what I would have:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file,header=None)
df
                       0       1
0                 132605       1
1                 132750       2
2                 # total: 100000
```

Is there a way to remove all rows that start with a comment character in-place -- that is, without having to re-load the data frame?

Comment: read_csv has parameter comment, you can use that comment = '#'

Comment: @Vaishali I know, I'm not able to pass that parameter to it though, as I need to keep the comment characters in the data frame for some other purposes.

Comment: Is  # total: in the first column and 100000 in the second column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `startswith`

```
newdf=df[df.iloc[:,0].str.startswith('#').ne(True)]
```

Comment: thanks -- is there a way to make that work with non-string columns as well? Otherwise I get: `AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas`. I.e., force the type to be string for the column

Comment: I think maybe: `df[df.iloc[:,0].astype(str).str.startswith('#').ne(True)]`  to cover the case where the first column may not be a string.

Comment: @David542 you can do with astype 1st

Answer (score 1):

Dataframe:

```
>>> df                                                                                                                 
          0       1
0    132605       1
1    132750       2
2  # total:  100000
3       foo     bar
```

Dropping in-place:

```
>>> to_drop = df[0].str.startswith('#').where(lambda s: s).dropna().index                                              
>>> df.drop(to_drop, inplace=True)                                                                                     
>>> df                                                                                                                 
        0    1
0  132605    1
1  132750    2
3     foo  bar
```

Assumptions: you want to find rows where the column labeled `0` starts with `'#'`. Otherwise, adjust accordingly.